# tag_configure does not apply background as excepted to tagged row

Tags: python, tkinter

It seems that I have an issue with `tag_configure` : nor size & color are taken into account :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

class ScrollTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master,ROW, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        sb = tk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical', command=self.yview) # Create a scrollbar
        sb.grid(row=ROW, column=2, sticky='ns')
        self.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    
    
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.tree_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.tree_frame.pack()
        self.load_data()
    
    def _SQL_ToTable(self,DF,ROW):
        try:
            columns_name = list(DF.columns.values.tolist()) 
            
            DF = list(DF.itertuples(index=False))
            print(DF)
            columns = [f'{columns_name[i]}' for i in range(len(DF[0]))] # List of column names for all the columns of the data
            tree = ScrollTree(self.tree_frame,ROW, columns=columns, show='headings')
            tree.grid(row=ROW, column=1)
    
            for col in columns:
                tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor='center') # Add a heading in the given `col` as ID
                tree.column(col, anchor='center') # Properties for the column with `col` as ID
    
            for i in DF:
                if i[2]==22:
                    Tag = "QTTKO"
                else:
                    Tag = "QTTOK"
        
                tree.insert('', 'end', values=i,tags=(Tag,)) # Insert each tuple into the treeview
            
            tree.tag_configure('QTTKO', background='red')
            tree.tag_configure('QTTOK', background='blue',font=({'family': 'Courier', 'size': 300, 'weight': 'normal'}))
        except:
            print("error")
            
            
    def load_data(self):
        data={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan'],'Age':[23,22,21,24],'AGEB':[23,22,21,24],'AGEC':[23,22,21,24]}
        df=pd.DataFrame(data)
        self._SQL_ToTable(df,0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong there ?

Ouptut :

[image]

playing with `size` does not even change the labels size .. And I see no colors on rows.

```
print(tk.TkVersion) --> 8.6
sys.version --> 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Also I am working on Spyder

Comment: When I run this code I see a tree with one red row and three blue rows. The font doesn't change because you've given it a bad font specification.

Comment: @BryanOakley do you see colors ? I've added a screenshot of what i see..

Comment: Yes, I see three blue rows and one red row.

Comment: @BryanOakley it is the output excepted, but why don't i see it on my screen ?

Comment: It is a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue36468) before tk 8.6.10.  Check the patch verion of tk you used.

Comment: @acw1668 How can I upgrade the tkinter version ?

Comment: Upgrade Python to 3.10 or 3.11.